# using Crystal Report with Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, crystal-reports

I have developed web site to have crystal report. The web site works fine in my PC. I have then transfer it to Azure. Once I transfer, it kept asking for dll files. I have then added all the dll files but finally it gave me this error:

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: What Azure service are you using?

Comment: web app service the standard one

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a runtime like the Crystal Reports runtime using App Service.  One solution is to use the virtual machine service that gives you more control on the OS and let you install 3rd party tools.